# How to remove an ObjectId from a ref array in a mongo schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this:

```
  var TestSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     ex: String,
     data:  [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Data'}]
  });
  var Test = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);
```

and it appears like this in RoboT:

[image]

what i want to do is to delete a data by its ID. i am doing this:

```
Test.update({}, {$pull: {data: idD }}, function(err, test) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.send({
        success: true
    })
});
```

where idD is the Data ID i want to delete. Before this i am doing just a simple

```
Data.deleteOne({_id: idD}, function...
```

and it works properly, but if i refresh the DB, my data with the idD is still present in the data array in Test Schema.
i have also tried:

```
Test.update({}, {$pull: {data: {_id:idD }},
Test.update({}, {$pull: {data: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idD)}}},
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use multi: true when you are updating multiple documents.

```
 Test.update({}, {$pull: {data: idD },{multi: true}, function(err, test) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.send({
            success: true
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you closed the particular collection window and opened it again or have you tried to reconnect your db in robot 3T?

Comment: i refresh both windows and in Data collection the data i want to eliminate disappears, but in the data array in the Test document it remains

Comment: Does the same Id appear in multiple collections? if yes then use { multi: true } in option.

Comment: nope every Test schema have different data IDs i their arrays

Comment: No want I want to ask is the same id you want to remove from the data array appears in the multiple documents? Like every collection has an array named Data, so multiple collections may contain the same id in their data array. right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $in with updateMany like this

```
Test.updateMany({},
  { $pull: { data: { $in: idToDelete } } }, { new: true }
)
```

if you wanna delete ObjectId ref at specific id User document the same but with updateOne

```
Test.updateOne({ _id: idUser },
  { $pull: { data: { $in: idToDelete } } }, { new: true }
)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting